# PHP Mysql create folder and new database for new registered user in my site

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu-12.04, zpanel

i wanna ask something..

Here is my explanation.

1. i have a php system that user can register and use my accounting system on it.
2. My accounting system is finished it can install `/` create database by itself when go to example : `www.mysystem.com/install/`
3. it is impossible for my system when new a user register. it creates a new database on my server and create subdomain like `newuser.mysystem.com` and automatically install my accounting system on his/her subdomain folder??
4. if its impossible, what the next step i should do?
5. let me know if you guys don't understand my explanation. English is my 2nd language.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. How? That's up to you...

Comment: well, yes. you'd have to recreate, in code, everything you'd do manually yourself to add a new user.

Comment: @MarcB can u give me some hint? did i need to play with my server database? to grand privilege to new user?

Comment: do you actually need to create a new database for each user? (i had the same thought when i started, and unless its a specific requirement of your project, you probably dont need to). [heres a basic tutorial for a login system](http://www.techyari.in/2014/10/multi-user-role-based-login-in-php-with-mysql.html).

Comment: @castis yes. i need to create new database for each user. because they also can edit my accounting system to suit their business. i dont know how to explain but in a nutshell this purpose is for business. XD

Comment: how many users do you estimate the application will have?

Comment: @castis it should be not more than 100. if more i will buy a bigger server and faster connection. :)

Comment: I dont mean to be disrespectful in any way but running 100 databases in tandem for a single project sounds like a really bad idea. What you want is possible but its also going to be a complexity nightmare. I'd learn how to create a single database with php first and go from there.

Comment: @castis actually this subdomain is not permanent. later they will get their own domain and my server will hosting their domain. it will be easy for me to backup their database later and move to their own domain. i know php and mysql very well. but i never do a project like this before. i hope u get the idea. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to know how good this worked for you. I sure hope it is future proof (and safe to a certain extent). Add a user only with CREATE and dump privileges to stay a little safe.

edit permission for temp files
`chmod 1777 /tmp`

```
<?php
/* this is for a test website I was building */
 $dbusername = "admin_user";
$dbuserpass = "secretPa$$";
$dbname="new_customer_DB"; //use a more unique name
 $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $dbusername, $dbuserpass, "your_admin_db");

    $sql = "CREATE DATABASE `".$dbname."` /*!DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;";


if ($mysqli->query($sql) ) {
    printf("$dbname successfully created.\n");
}

// dump database from master db into newly created one.
// dbname and masterdb are important
$masterdb ="customer_db_template";
$olduser= $dbusername;




$file = tempnam("/tmp", "FOO");

 $content= "[client]\n";
$content.= "user=$dbusername \n";
$content.= "password=$dbuserpass \n";
$content.= "host=localhost";
file_put_contents($file, $content);

print "<hr> ";

$cmd = "mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=$file --routines --opt $masterdb | mysql --defaults-extra-file=$file --host=localhost -C $dbname;";
print $cmd;
print "<pre>"; 

  system( $cmd   );  
unlink($file); //delete right away
mysqli::close ($mysqli );
print "</pre>";
?>
```

power answerers : how did I do?